# how to make people to login into specific app with their gmail account or facebook account

Tags: android

I am new to android and I want to create an android application to access specific app with signup or login with gmail or faceebook account (how to make people to login into specific app with their gmail account or facebook account).

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

You integrate already exists SDK's to your app. There are very detailed tutorials, and I gave 2 examples (FB, Google) but almost everybody have such things (Twitter etc.)

When you done - You will have the well known designed login buttons...